# How to make elements of several lists into one in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, append

I'm trying to take a list of lists of lists (don't worry, I'll put an example) and convert the elements of each last least into one.
This is what I've done so far:

```
(defun cost(state)
(let ((list_elements '()))
(dolist (element state)
  (dolist (subElement element)
    (setq list_elements (append list_elements (list subElement))))
finally (return list_elements))))
```

Example:

```
(list
(list
    (list
        (list 1 9 't121) 
        (list 1 10 't122))
    (list
        (list 2 10 't123)
        (list 2 11 't124)))
(list
    (list
        (list 1 9 't121)
        (list 1 11 't132))
    (list
        (list 2 11 't133)
        (list 2 12 't134))))
```

So, this is supposed to return 
`((1 9 T121) (1 10 T122) (2 10 T123) (2 11 T124) (1 9 T121) (1 11 T132) (1 11 T132) (2 11 T133) (2 12 T134))`
And it is only returning `((1 9 T121) (1 11 T132))`

After that, I'm supposed to count the number of different elements in the list.

Does anyone see what the problem is in this function?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun double-append (list)
  (reduce #'append (reduce #'append list)))

;; or like this:
(defun mapcan-mapcon (list)
  (mapcan #'append (mapcon #'car list)))

(double-append (list
 (list
  (list
   (list 1 9 't121) 
   (list 1 10 't122))
  (list
   (list 2 10 't123)
   (list 2 11 't124)))
 (list
  (list
   (list 1 9 't121)
   (list 1 11 't132))
  (list
   (list 2 11 't133)
   (list 2 12 't134)))))

((1 9 T121) (1 10 T122) (2 10 T123) (2 11 T124) (1 9 T121) (1 11 T132)
 (2 11 T133) (2 12 T134))
```

So far I could tell by the expected result, that must be something like it.

```
;; Using Alexandria, just as an example, of how currying can save
;; some repetitive coding:
(ql:quickload "alexandria")
(defun curried-append ()
  (let ((reducer (alexandria:curry #'reduce #'append)))
    (alexandria:compose reducer reducer)))

(funcall
 (curried-append)
 (list
  (list
   (list
    (list 1 9 't121) 
    (list 1 10 't122))
   (list
    (list 2 10 't123)
    (list 2 11 't124)))
  (list
   (list
    (list 1 9 't121)
    (list 1 11 't132))
   (list
    (list 2 11 't133)
    (list 2 12 't134)))))
```

Comment: That's almost it. That functions returns this: 
`(1 9 T121 1 11 T132 2 11 T133 2 12 T134 3 11 T111 3 10 T001)` but that's ok, found the solution

Comment: Do you know how I can find the number of different elements in a list?

Comment: I asked Google, and for the first time in my life, he didn't know the answer (or didn't want to show it o me)